# How to add new file to array

Tags: reactjs

Hi guys I'm new in react ,I try to add new file in array but it's not work

This is the code

```
const [mymy, setMymy] = useState([
    { name: "riky", age: "15" },
    { name: "budi", age: "22" },
  ]);
  function mantap() {
    console.log(mymy);
    setMymy(mymy + { name: "paijo", age: "33" });
    console.log(mymy);
  }
```

Can someone explain to me why it's not work and how to fix it ? Thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a new element to the state array like:

`setTheArray([...theArray, newElement]);`

---

Also, you can't get the updated value immediately after `setMyMy`. You should get the updated value in the `useEffect` with adding a dependency.

```js
const [mymy, setMymy] = useState([
    { name: "riky", age: "15" },
    { name: "budi", age: "22" },
]);

function mantap() {
  setMymy([...mymy, {
    name: "paijo",
    age: "33"
  }]);
}

useEffect(() => {
  console.log(mymy);
}, [ mymy ]);
```

Comment: btw, i updated answer again to check the mymy value